# How to jump to the end of a transition in D3?

Tags: d3.js

Let's say I have a transtition going on such as

```
svg.select('rect')
   .transition()
   .duration(5000)
   .attr('opacity', 0)
   .each('end',function() {
       d3.select(this).remove()
   });
```

Is there a way to jump to the end of that transition and trigger the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 does not seem to provide a way to jump to the final state of the transition but one can interrupt the transition and use a specific callback on interruption to set the element as intended:

```
svg.select('rect')
   .transition()
   .duration(5000)
   .attr('opacity', 0)
   .each('end',function() {
       d3.select(this).remove();
   })
   .each('interrupt',function() {
       // This is called when the transition is interrupted
       d3.select(this).remove();
   });

setTimeout(function() {
    // This interrupts any ongoing transitions
    svg.select('rect').transition();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question -- this does *not* jump to the end of a transition, it only interrupts it. In particular the state of the element will be the state when it was interrupted, not the state it would have at the end of transition. In your example this doesn't make a difference because you're removing the element, but in general this will *not* work as the question suggests.

Comment: This is a good point I reworded the answer so that it's presented as a workaround since D3 does not seem to offer this possibility. Effectively it is possible to reach any state in the interrupt callback.

Comment: Well you're executing the code that's run after the end of the transition, not setting the state at the end of the transition. And yes, you can reach any state in a transition by executing arbitrary code. I would strongly suggest changing the title of the question; it is misleading at the moment.

Comment: The question reflects what I and possibly others were looking for, and the answer the best way I found to achieve this. If there is a better way I would gladly accept it as answer.